# Pagination and form tag issue

Tags: mysql, forms, pagination

i have two .php files: trialform.php and trialaction.php

User chooses search terms using `<select>` tags on trialform.php, and then that information goes to trialaction.php that has mySQL `$query=SELECT * ...` which contains variables like $expression1 etc. *(Depending on the user's choice).*

It works fine. But I wanted to implement `pagination` from this [source](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html)
Now my query works only for the first pagination page, when I click on the second and third...it does not show any results. The problem is that the `$query=SELECT * ...` refers to trialform.php, and it does not exist after the user pressed "Submit".

Do I have to split my `$_POST` code section in a separate  .php file in order to be able to use `pagination` and `<form>`?

Comment: You just have to remember the thing the user selected. It doesn't have to do anything to do with using a `<form>` tag. Put their choice in a session variable or put it as a hidden input on the resulting page. There's nothing that says your pagination has to be done as a GET request either

Comment: @Cfreak I thought that $_POST array kept the values as a session variable would do. Does $_POST flushe its memory as user "paginates" though pages?

Comment: `$_POST` only contains the variables that are submitted through a POST request. Usually whatever your form variables are in `<form method="post" action="somescript.php">` ... so yes they are only available for the current request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is often performed with parameters on subsequent pages passing updates to the page number (gets you the start parameter) and limit as can be seen here http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/paging.html

and viewing the http headers in fiddler. for page 4 you get

GET /forum/topics-browse-remote.php?_dc=1368498808032&page=4&start=150&limit=50

and page 5 is

GET /forum/topics-browse-remote.php?_dc=1368498808032&page=5&start=200&limit=50

so subsequent pages (prior or next) know where to start. naturally the parameters are fed into the select statement such as 
select * from employee limit 200,50      # start,limit